# How to get Doctrine2 entity identifier without knowing its name

Tags: entity, doctrine-orm, identifier, symfony

I am attempting to create an abstracted getId method on my base Entity class in Symfony2 using Doctrine2 for a database where primary keys are named inconsistently across tables.

When inspecting entity objects I see there is a private '_identifier' property that contains the information I am trying to retrieve but I am not sure how to properly access it.

I'm assuming there is some simple Doctrine magic similar to:

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->getIdentifier();
}
```

But I haven't managed to find it on the intertubes anywhere.

Comment: Do you have any way to normalize your identifiers, or is that out of your control?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Most tables are named TablenameID, but some are CmpTablenameID. They are all annotated via @orm:Id in their respective entity though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can access this information via `EntityManager#getClassMetadata()`. An example would look like this:

```
// $em instanceof EntityManager
$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
$identifier = $meta->getSingleIdentifierFieldName();
```

If your entity has a composite primary key, you'll need to use `$meta->getIdentifierFieldNames()` instead. Of course, using this method, you'll need access to an instance of `EntityManager`, so this code is usually placed in a [custom repository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) rather than in the entity itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can see the thread in the doctrine-user Google group where I unintentionally found this answer because of a different problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/7I4VYhwV_0Y).

Comment: Is there any way to access this information from the entity instead of the repository?

Comment: I suppose you could pass into the constructor. Or, if you have some control of your entities, implement an IdentifiableInterface or something and return it manually. There's no magic to do this, as entities are simply plain old PHP objects.

Comment: Actually, this can be handled with reflection in java. So i guess, can be solved by reflection in php as well